# group and combine NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray called matches which contains other objects called games. Games is a collection of games.title,  games.players, games.dates.

my code is as follows;

```
 for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++)
 {
        games = [[Games alloc] init];
        games.title= [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"titleJson"];
        games.date= [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"dateJson"];
        NSString *players=[[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"playersJson"];
        arrayPlayers= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:playersJson, nil];
        play.players=players;        
        [matches addobject: games]
  }
```

I am able to print this on uitableview well as well as players on detail view, however there are repeating values such as

```
[Match 1, May 2013, striker 1]
[Match 1, May 2014, striker 2]
[Match 2, May 2014, striker 1]
```

How do I combine match 1, so that I can have this result;

```
[Match 1, May 2013, May2014, striker 1, sticker 2]
[Match 2, May 2014, striker 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [key-value programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).

```
NSArray *distictResult = [matches valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.games.title"];
```

Comment: I tried it but I am getting this error "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key games"

Comment: Please go through the link posted.